# How to use ffmpeg hwaccel d3d11va decode?

Tags: ffmpeg, directx-11

I'm trying to use ffmpeg(3.4) hwaccel d3d11va to decode multiple rtsp streams for video surveillance. I want to get the decode the frames to an existing ID3D11Texture2D texture directly, without ID3D11DeviceContext->Map/Unmap operations.

I have seen the examples\hw_decode.c, the sample use av_hwframe_transfer_data to get data from GPU to CPU, but I want to decode frames to an existing ID3D11Texture2D texture directly, or copy to an existing ID3D11Texture2D texture.

How can I do that? Thanks.